Parsing .eml file with winmail.dat: Extracting Original HTML, Body, and Attachments
I'm working on parsing .eml files that contain a winmail.dat attachment, specifically when the .eml file has the following headers:
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

My goal is to extract:

The raw HTML of the email
The plain text body, and
Any attachments that were included in the email (not the
.dat attachment).

The winmail.dat file encapsulates the email's formatting (such as RTF content), but I want to extract only the original HTML, body, and any genuine attachments.
I've attempted using tnefparse to handle the TNEF (Transport Neutral Encapsulation Format) data, but I need advice on how best to identify and retrieve the actual content from within this .eml file.
